# Using a certain drawable under certain conditions in an Adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom calendar view which I want to display certain drawables depending on if the day is selected or if the that specific day is the current date

current date image

[image]

and this would be the selected date image

[image]

I have a selector for the for selecting the date which works as expected but if I select the current date and then select another, the current date image does not show just the number without a circle like any other date would look that was not selected.

so the question is, how can I change the background back to the current date one after a new date has been selected since they are 2 different drawables?

here is my selector for the selected date background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/day_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/day_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/day_selected"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/day_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_day"/>
</selector>
```

and the today drawable is just a shape drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#cbcbcb"/>

</shape>
```

this is part of my adapter

```
final TextView dayTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    Day d = dayList.get(position);
    if(d.getYear() == cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) && d.getMonth() == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) && d.getDay() == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
        dayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.today);
    }

    dayTV.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
                Day d = dayList.get(position);
                if(d.getYear() == cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) && d.getMonth() == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) && d.getDay() == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                    dayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.today);
                }else{
                    dayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.date_number_background);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I thought using `onFocusChangeListener` would work but it never gets focus and using `onClickListener` to set focus just messes everything up